# Node.js: How to receive STDOUT and STDERR from executed binary?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pipe, stdout, stderr

Suppose I have a program `foo`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << "a1" << std::endl;
  std::cerr << "b2" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "c3" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
enter code here
```

When executed via terminal it prints

```
a1
b2
c3
```

You can get this output to file in bash via `foo &> out.log` or simply by `foo 2>&1` but how would you do that using `node.js`?

`execFile` returns stdout and stderr separately (with no way to find out their original positions in the output). Connecting to `data` events also doesn't work because it looks like it does internal buffering and sometimes bundles two stdout lines together even though they were separated by stderr.
So in both approached my js program more often than not prints

```
a1
c3
b2
```

instead of desired output. I really don't want to execute `foo` through bash proxy only to get proper stderr redirection.

Comment: The redirection itself is not the problem. The difference is probably in how the output is buffered by the generating program. When your program runs from the shell, the file descriptors reference your `tty` device (or your OS equivalent). From Node, the file descriptors reference pipes (or equivalent), and it's likely that the buffering (on the C++ side) is different. Independent open file descriptors don't have any ordering. If you really want to maintain some ordering, use a single file descriptor instead of two.

Comment: @Pointy Hm, but `foo` flushes cerr/cout after every output.

Comment: Really? Is that guaranteed behavior from `std::endl`? Isn't that just the line terminator? (What platform are you on?) There's also `std::flush`.

Comment: @Pointy yes, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl `endl` adds line terminator and flushes the stream. `'\n'` is just a line terminator.